# Compiling with "Any CPU" works, but x64 and x86 result in Namespace not found

Tags: .net, vb.net, uwp, visual-studio-2022

I am baffled:

When I set my project to use Any CPU, it works and compiles fine.

When I switch to x86 or x64, the compiler says "Windows.Devices.WiFi does not contain any public members":

```
Imports Windows.Devices.WiFi

Public Class AvailWifiNetwork

    Public Wifi As WiFiAvailableNetwork
    Public HasWPS As Boolean
    Public WeAreConnectedToIt As Boolean
    Public Strength As Double

End Class
```

Why is that?

[image]

Comment: It is a UWP app or a WinForms app?

Comment: It's a Winforms app with make use of some UWP elements and references the PresentationFramework.